# Single action is required when uploading the image over the canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to uploading the image over the canvas html control but what is the problem is when I uploading the image at first time, that image is not uploading in canvas html and again if I select that same image then that image is uploading in canvas very well.That means, in my scenario if user first upload the image over the canvas then they should upload the image twice but what I want when user first upload the image then that image should be display over the canvas.Please check the below script and html5 tag whether I am doing some mistake please suggest me how to resolve that kind of issue. Thanks in advance.

```
<!--HTML5 tags Implementation-->

    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
     <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>

<!--JavaScript Implementation-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageLoader = '';
        var canvas = '';
        var ctx = '';

        function readURL(input) {
            //alert('test');
            imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
            //imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage,false);
            imageLoader.addEventListener('change', this.handleImage.bind(this), false);
            canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        };

        function handleImage(e) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var img = new Image();
                console.log(img);
                img.onload = function () {
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution about this issue.Actually, I was implementing the javascript and it calls change event is twice which creates the problem when user upload the image over the canvas at first time.So, I am familiar with jquery so I was implementing the jquery and solve this issue please check the below code thoroughly then you will understood.

```
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>

<!--JQuery Implementation-->

<script type="text/javascript>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#imageLoader').on('change', function (e) {
            imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
            canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            handleImage(e);

        })
});
 function handleImage(e) {
        alert('check');
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var img = new Image();
            //console.log(img);
            img.onload = function () {
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    };
</script>
```